# How to fix the member "encodeCall" not found in abi error?

Tags: solidity, ether, evm, abi

I'm writing a smart contract that calls another contract using it's `address` and `abi.encodeCall`, however when I compile my code I get this error message: `Member "encodeCall" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in abi.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`abi.encodeCall` was released in solidity version 0.8.11, so check the version of solidity you are using. By changing your `pragma` line to `pragma solidity ^0.8.11` you should be able to compile successfully.